# Como Configurar editor de texto para git

Tags: git, github

pessoal estou tentando aqui configurar o editor do git para o sublime porem esta dando erro, alguem sabe como realizar essa configuração da forma correta?
estava tentando algo como isso
git config --global core.editor "subl -w"

Answer (score 1):

`git config --global core.editor "subl -n -w"`

[Fonte](https://help.github.com/articles/associating-text-editors-with-git/#using-sublime-text-as-your-editor)

Observação: se o sublime não foi adicionado as suas variáveis de ambiente, você precisa informar o caminho completo até o aplicativo ao invés de apenas `subl`. Exemplo:

`git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text.exe' -n -w"`

Comment: esse -n e -w sabe para que serve?

Comment: `-n` é para que uma nova janela/aba seja aberta e o `-w` é para que o git "espere" até você fechar o editor.

Answer (score 0):

As vezes você precisa também alem desses comandos acima é necessário inserir o e-mail e o nome do autor do commit. Veja abaixo:

`git config --global user.email "nome@seuemail.com"`

`git config --global user.name "seu nome"`

Aí o sublime funciona normalmente.